# JavaScript: Add Key and Value to Object Using ES6 {} Shortcut

Tags: javascript, function, object, ecmascript-6, key-value

I have the following object:

```
obj = {name: 'Amy',
       age: 36,
       type: 'sanguine'}
```

I want to add another key and value to the above object, but I specifically want to do that using the {} shortcut.

This is an example of using the {} shortcut:

```
function test (bloodtype) {
  return { bloodtype }
}

test('A')
```

Result: `{ index: 0, elem: 22 }`

But trying to add bloodtype to obj using that shortcut doesn't work.

```
function test (bloodtype) {
      return obj{ bloodtype }
}

test('A')
```

Error:

```
evalmachine.<anonymous>:31
  return obj{ bloodtype }
            ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As it says, that's not the right syntax. `{ ...obj, bloodtype }` will create a new object, or `obj.bloodtype = bloodtype` will add to the existing object.

Comment: How does `test('A')` return `{ index: 0, elem: 22 }`

Comment: You could also modify the existing object with `Object.assign( obj, { bloodtype } );`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use the shortcut syntax, you first need to use the [object spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and then merge it with your new property:

```
function test (obj, bloodtype) {
  return {...obj, bloodtype};
}
```